# Artist's most popular city on spotify api

Tags: spotify

is it possible, through the spotify api, to access an artist's most popular city? it allows you to view it on the mobile app and on the desktop app, but not the web app. example below:

example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

this is currently not available, there is an enhancement request for [this feature](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/188)